# Pagination on group result

Tags: solr, pagination, grouping

I'm new to Solr. I have been trying to use pagination with my grouping documents on Solr. The cursorMark was working great before I added the grouping feature.
Is there a way to do grouping with pagination?

[The link with grouping feature](https://example.com/solr/my_core/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=*&q=food%20night&group=true&group.field=myType&group.limit=-1)

[The link without grouping feature](https://example.com/solr/my_core/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=*&q=panadol%20night&group=true&group.ngroups=true&group.field=myType&group.limit=-1&sort=singlekey%20desc&&cursorMark=*)

Comment: Since grouping is a separate operation from the regular query results, cursorMarks won't apply. You might have more luck with the [Collapse and Expand](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collapse-and-expand-results.html) functionality instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for your response. I try Collapse and Expand ```select?wt=json&q=pasta&fq={!collapse%20field=myType}&expand=true&expand.rows=10``` but the result not as expected, and some result appears inside response parentheses while other results appear inside expanded parentheses. Also how to do pagination when using Collapse and Expand?

Comment: You should be able to use the regular pagination, since the collapsed resultset is what will be sent downstream. If you want to stick with the group format, you'll have to use the regular `start` and `rows` parameters afaik.

Comment: @MatsLindh I can't use start and rows parameters with the group format because after searching for a term the result not sorted.

Comment: What part of sorting are you thinking of? You have the `sort` parameter to sort the groups themselves, and `group.sort` to sort inside the group.